# creating a pop-up in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I wanted to create a pop-up with option buttons and textbox..

check my codes..

```
<form id="frmInsuranceCarrier" runat="server">
    <div>Enter a New Insurance Carrier Code</div>
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="optAutoAssign" runat="server" />
    &nbsp;Auto Assign</div>
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="optManual" runat="server" />
    &nbsp;Manual</div>
     <div>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtManual" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" onclick="cmdOk_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
        onclick=
```

"cmdCancel_Click" />

Answer (score 0):

there's not much code here in dealing with a popup : )
Do you want an ajax modal popup? in that case check out:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Jquery model is a good choice.

[How to use jquery dialog in asp.net](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-jquery-dialog-in-aspnet.html)

[jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

you can use the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)

to execute every javascript/jQuery Code Serverside

```
public void AnyButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "$('#theid').dialog('open');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", script, true);
}
```